# MySQL is slow in executing queries

Tags: mysql

The following is the list of process in my database

[image]

Is there anyways to solve my database performance problem. Whenever I run mysql query it takes about 1 minute or more than 1.

And find the following image to retrieve some records from the database it takes even longer.

[image]

Comment: are you running a complex join or a simple select?  Do you log slow queries? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: either you have a lot of concurrent users or some application is not disposing of used connections properly

Comment: good point ADyson, maybe you have an application that's not executing mysql_close() or its non-PHP equivalent

Comment: Are you meaning to sleep the queries? Looks like that could make the queries appear slow?

Comment: SELECT vw.id, vw.workorder_id, vw.workorder, vw.project_name, vw.workorder_status, vw.enduser_name, vw.read_status, CONCAT(vt.first_name, ' ', vt.last_name) AS technician FROM velociti_work_order AS vw LEFT JOIN velociti_technician vt ON vw.lead_technician_id = vt.technician_id WHERE vw.workorder_status IN ('Scheduled', 'Rescheduled') ORDER BY vw.project_name ASC LIMIT 0, 25;

Comment: the query doesn't look too complex in itself. Are there a lot of rows in your tables? Have you got proper keys and indexes on them? how powerful is your hardware? What table engine are you using? there are a lot of things which go into the recipe of good performance, I'm sure there is more that others could suggest too. You need to look into what I wrote above re the number of connections too

Comment: There are about 8000 rows in the table.

Comment: plus I'm concerned there are so many connections open as "root" user - applications should have their own limited logins to improve security. Have you got a lot of DBAs??

Comment: Are there a lot of rows in your tables? - 8000. Have you got proper keys and indexes on them? - I did not define any index. how powerful is your hardware? - 16GB RAM.

Comment: no index at all? not even on the primary keys? 8000 is a fairly trivial number of rows.

Comment: If I create view for the above query will my performance improve on retrieving from database?

Comment: No - although you could have proved that for yourself in the time it took to ask us.

Comment: As a minimum, questions about query performance always require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, as well as the EXPLAIN. In addition, I think it sensible to provide an MCVE (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)